# SearchBar in UINavigationItem will not be first controller

Tags: ios, objective-c, cocoa-touch

I have a UISearchBar in my UINavigationItem like so:

```
searchBar = [[UISearchBar alloc] init];
[searchBar setDelegate:self];
self.navigationItem.titleView = searchBar;
```

Then in my table view I use:

```
-(void)scrollViewWillBeginDragging:(UIScrollView *)scrollView
{
    [self.searchBar resignFirstResponder];
}
```

--so that the keyboard will disappear if the user scrolls through the results.

However, now when I click on the search bar again, I can't get it to pull up the keyboard. I figured the view would do it automatically but it doesn't (clearly). I tried:

```
-(void)searchBarTextDidBeginEditing:(UISearchBar *)searchBar
{
    [searchBar becomeFirstResponder];
}
```

It didn't work (and I didn't expect it to)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`searchBarTextDidBeginEditing` is not going to be called until after the search bar becomes first responder, so clearly your `becomeFirstResponder` call is not even being called.

I am just as surprised as you are that the search bar does not just automatically become first responder when it is tapped. Is some other code (not shown above) disabling it? Did you implement `searchBarShouldBeginEditing:` to return NO?

EDIT: After chat, turned out the problem was that he was not assigning the UISearchBar a frame (as you can see from his code).

Comment: Ya I'm confused. I don't see anything else that it could be. Could it have something to do with the fact thats its inside a nav item?

Comment: Not in my experience. Not directly, anyway. It should be a view like any other view; the fact that you have to do this dance to put it into the nav bar shouldn't matter. I often put tappable things as the titleView of a navigation item. You could double-check to see that userInteractionEnabled is YES, I suppose. But the question remains why was it tappable once and not later?

Comment: In fact I just tried it using all the code you've given and it worked fine (no need for searchBarTextDidBeginEditing). You must be doing something else you're not telling us. (I did have to say `sizeToFit` to the search bar, otherwise it's tiny. But I presume you are giving it a frame in some code you didn't show.)

Comment: Right sorry I forgot to mention, in viewDidAppear I have:     [self.searchBar performSelector:@selector(becomeFirstResponder) withObject:nil afterDelay:0.2f];

But, when I left that out, the search bar was NOT tappable either. So its not tappable at all. I tried setting the userInteractionEnabled to yes and it didnt help.

Comment: Also I didnt have a sizeToFit...it just fit automatically...maybe we're running different versions...I'm running 4.6. I'm grabbing at straws though.

Comment: I didn't have to do that viewDidAppear thing; the search bar was just tappable from the get-go. So clearly your search bar was *never* tappable (good, at least it's consistent). Could there be something else sitting in front of the search bar that you're not telling us about, blocking it?

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/27449/discussion-between-joshdg-and-matt)